# Calling a function from Type::new()

Tags: parsing, rust

I have the following code in Go that I'd like to re-write in Rust:

```golang
func New(l *lexer.Lexer) *Parser {
    p := &Parser{l: l}
    // Read two tokens, so curToken and peekToken 
    // are both set
    p.nextToken()
    p.nextToken()
    return p
}
func (p *Parser) nextToken() {
    p.curToken = p.peekToken
    p.peekToken = p.l.NextToken()
}
```

In Rust, I have something as follows:

```rust
struct Parser {
    l: lexer::Lexer,
    cur_token: lexer::Token,
    peek_token: lexer::Token,
}
impl Parser {
    fn new(l: lexer::Lexer, cur_token: lexer::Token, peek_token: lexer::Token) -> Self {
        Self {
            l: l,
            cur_token: cur_token,
            peek_token: peek_token,
        }
    }
    fn init(&mut self) {
        self.next_token();
        self.next_token();
    }
    fn next_token(&mut self) {
        self.cur_token = self.peek_token;
        self.peek_token = self.l.next_token();
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to write the code in rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only change you'd make in Rust is to retrieve the first two tokens before constructing `Parser`, since values can't be null. There's no need to separate `new` into two functions or to take extra parameters.

```rust
fn new(mut l: lexer::Lexer) -> Self {
    let cur_token = l.next_token();
    let peek_token = l.next_token();
    Self {
        l,
        cur_token,
        peek_token,
    }
}
```

If you had to ensure `Parser::next_token` was called, you could initialize `Parser` with temporary values. It doesn't matter which values you choose as long as they are valid, but here I'm using `Token::default`.

```rust
fn new(l: lexer::Lexer) -> Self {
    let mut parser = Self {
        l,
        cur_token: lexer::Token::default(),
        peek_token: lexer::Token::default(),
    };
    parser.next_token();
    parser.next_token();
    parser
}
```